Increasing data via RBF neural networks
Is there a code that can increase the number of data in one dataset with the help of a RBF neural network?  A special design should be created for the model?  Is there no pre-made model?  Is there another neural network for data augmentation?  The main dataset has 20 features and 65 samples!
